# Simultaneously Adding / Removing GradientLayer among Three Buttons

Tags: ios, swift, cagradientlayer

lets say I have three buttons , the functionality is that when button is selected i dont want to add MygradientLayer for that button and want for other two Buttons..

For Adding and Removing GradientLayer i created a extension For UIView as below:

```
extension UIView {

    private var gradientLayer : CAGradientLayer {

        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
        gradientLayer.colors = arrButtonColors.map({$0.cgColor})
        return gradientLayer
    }

    open func applyGradientColor() {
        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
    }

    open func removeGradientLayer() {

       gradientLayer.removeFromSuperlayer() --// this does't remove gradientLayer at all

       self.layer.sublayers?.removeAll() --// this will remove all the layer include UILabelLayer , that doesn't i want

      self.layer.sublayers = nil --// same effect as above(2nd condition)

    }

}
```

***My functionality code in ViewController:***

```
if view.isHidden {
            btn.applyGradientColor()
        } else  {
            btn.removeGradientLayer()
        }
```

*I know that if btn(Button) doesn't have any layer(exclude UILabelLayer) then it will
     add GradientLayer otherwise not , for that i tried to remove all the 
    sublayer first and even tried to remove sublayer at 0 index in view.isHidden block. 
allthough it also doesn't work.*

***functionality code will execute three times for differnet object of UIButton***

How to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't hold a reference to previously added `gradientLayer`. You have to retain it. One way is to subclass it and retain the variable in there Or you can also retain it with extension in runtime using `objc_setAssociatedObject`.

Here's a sample of how you can do this:

```
private var key = "gradientLayerKey"
extension UIView {
    private var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer? {
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &key) as? CAGradientLayer
        }

        set {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &key, newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
        }
    }

    private var gradientLayerInstance: CAGradientLayer {
        let newGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        newGradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
        newGradientLayer.colors = arrButtonColors.map { $0.cgColor }
        return newGradientLayer
    }

    open func applyGradientColor() {
        gradientLayer?.removeFromSuperLayer()
        // next line sets gradientLayer and retains it.
        gradientLayer = gradientLayerInstance
        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
    }

    open func removeGradientLayer() {
        gradientLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()
    }
}
```

Comment: nice farzadshbfn , i tried your code and its work for me , happy to know new concept today like objc_setAssociatedObject . Thanks

Comment: okay but any other way to find out the  gradientLayer which we just inserted , i am talking about to cut the code little as per  Duncan C suggestion like for loop in removeGradientLayer() method.

Comment: well why not just setting `gradientLayer` as public?, I set it as private to follow your code, but if you don't mark it as private and you can access it from everywhere. either that or i didn't quite understand your question :D

Comment: @farzadshbfn, you're using a custom getter/setter and associated objects to simulate a stored property, which is another option. You can't add stored properties to an extension (unless you use associated objects like in your answer.)

Comment: @DuncanC well this is the only way to semi-store properties in extensions. and it only works with classes. Sometimes they come-in handy, specially in using libraries.

Comment: Yup, I've used that trick in Objective-C a fair amount, but haven't used it much in Swift.

Comment: It sounds like the OP is asking how to manage a gradientLayer without using your trick. The code I suggested should work.

Answer (score 0):

You've made `gradientLayer` a computed property. That means you get a new layer every time you read the property. Make it a regular property instead.

That probably means you have to use a subclass of UIButton, not an extension. Alternately, make your remove code loop through all the sublayers and only remove the gradient layer.

### EDIT:

The code to find and remove the gradient layer might look like this:

```
open func removeGradientLayer() {
   if let layers = layer.subLayers {
     for aLayer in layers {
       if aLayer is CAGradientLayer {
         aLayer.removeFromSuperlayer
         break
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: hey Duncan first of all thanks for reply , but is there any other  way to create a subclass of UIButton ? why not with Extension ?

Comment: You can't create stored properties in an extension, and you need some way to get to the gradient layer in order to remove it. If you subclass UIButton you can use a stored property which will let you remove it. The other alternative, as I mentioned, would be to loop through the sublayers and remove the first gradient layer you find.

Comment: yeah i know that we can't create a stored properties in extension and thats why i created private computed property , but its okay Duncan , i tried your code , its work but only for my 2nd button among three buttons..! its means its found a CAGradientLayer for 2nd Button Only

Comment: I tried this one : self.layer.sublayers?.forEach({$0.removeFromSuperlayer()})
but this will remove the UILabelLayer

Comment: Ok, you need to debug your code to figure out why your other buttons aren't finding their gradient layers. The `sublayers?.forEach()` code will always remove every layer, so it's no different than your original `sublayers?.removeAll()` code.

Comment: yupp , but i also tried your code  Duncan C , it doesn't work.!

Comment: So you need to debug it.